# Migrating mounts with identical permissions not working

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-14.04, rsync, mount

I have two mounts `/mount1` and `/mount2`. I ran the command:

```
rsync -azrt /mount1/* /mount2/
```

to clone everything from `/mount1` to `/mount2`.

I then altered the `/etc/fstab` *(see below)* to remove `/mount1` and mount `/mount2` to `/mount1` but things (including my email servers local user folders) are not working properly for permission reasons anymore, even though when comparing the permissions with the mounts before and after they are identical?!

---

#### `/etc/fstab` before (working):

```
UUID="3999A4F22570EAC4" /mount2   ntfs-3g nobootwait,permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
mhddfs#/mount3,/mount4 /mount1 fuse defaults,allow_other,nobootwait,nonempty,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 0
```

#### `/etc/fstab` after (not working):

```
UUID="3999A4F22570EAC4" /mount1   ntfs-3g nobootwait,permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
```

<sub>Where `UUID="3999A4F22570EAC4"` is `/mount2` that has the content of the previous `/mount1`</sub>

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [sf] instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you'll have to add uid and gid as done for fuse to make sure it belongs to you at the end.

See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207180/changing-permissions-in-fstab-in-order-to-allow-writing-in-windows-ntfs-partitio) .